# The link to the election is messed up for the new election badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

[As seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1974/constituent), for example. The "for an election" link doesn't work. More specifically, it has backslashes in it for some reason:

```
\election\3
```

I'm guessing these should be forward slashes.

Also, while I'm at it, the links should be absolute, not relative. Thanks to the new notifications system, I read about my Gaming Constituent badge on MSO. It linked me to `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/\election\2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notifications will append the site after the next build.